# CSS How to Transition from White to Background on Hover

Tags: css, background, hover, transition

I'm trying to create a transition from a white background to an image background. This way when the viewer hovers over a section it goes from plain to styled.

Here's my current code:

```
div.camp {
     background: #FFFFFF;
      border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; 
      border-radius: 8px; 
     padding: 8px; 
      transition: all 1s linear 0s;
  }
div.camp:hover {
      background: #EFFFD5 url("http://www.alpinejosh.com/host/sp/images/camp.png"); 
        background-position: center bottom; 
       background-repeat: repeat-x; 
    border: 1px solid #CECECE;
  }
```

Here's the page this code is on: http://www.summitpost.org/eldorado-peak/150316#chapter_7

From what I understand it's easy to have background colors transition. But it seems as though background images are not supported for transition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use transition on background images in the way you've specified. You can see the [W3C list of animation property types here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animation-of-property-types-).

You could potentially lay your white background over the top, then animate its opacity on hover (to show the image beneath).

**Code Sample**

You could obviously make this prettier. I've just cobbled something together to give you an idea.

```
div.camp {
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; 
  background: #EFFFD5 url("http://www.alpinejosh.com/host/sp/images/camp.png"); 
  background-position: center bottom; 
  background-repeat: repeat-x; 
  border-radius: 8px; 
  position: relative;
}

div.camp-overlay {
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:50;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background:white;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

div.camp-overlay:hover {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0);  /* use opacity for older browsers*/
}​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**HTML for the above CSS**

```
<div class="camp">
    <div class="camp-overlay"></div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**JSFiddle of the above**

http://jsfiddle.net/p7mcy/

Comment: Wow! This looks great. Too bad it's not possible to do this in a single DIV element. Oh well. Hope in the future of CSS other elements are added to the opacity property. Anyways a big thanks. I can't wait to test out this code.

Comment: @JoshLewis Hope it works for you. Please don't forget to mark this as the answer if it *does* work :)

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is make two div elements, one on top of the other, and fade top div out on hover.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="white-bg"></div>
</div>

.wrapper{position:relative;}
.image, .white-bg{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100px; height:50px;}
.image{background:red;}
.white-bg{background:white; z-index:9999; -webkit-transition:opacity 0.3s linear; opacity:1;}
.white-bg:hover{opacity:0;}​
```

Should work
fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b46z8/5/

Comment: I appreciate your reply. In your example page it doesn't seem to fade out based on the time you give it. (I am currently using Firefox Version 17)

Comment: My example only works for webkit based browsers. To use transitions in firefox you need to add -moz-transition:opacity 0.3s linear;